# Missing objects when saving .svg as .pdf with Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, pdf, svg

I am using `Inkscape`.

I have the following `.svg` file ([here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hsomccp0snq79m4/AADWuMUD15YG821yQTvLLwqUa?dl=0)):

[image]

When I choose `Save as copy` and `.pdf`, I get the following (also in previous link):

[image]

I tried grouping, ungrouping and moving layers, the bottom left figure still does not appear. It is a `.png` figure, not vector, but that has worked in the past with our examples... Why does it not appear in the pdf?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What software are you using? What is the graphic that's disappearing? Vector? Raster?

Comment: Sorry, I am such an idiot for not writing this in the question (edited one): Inkscape

Comment: The XML is a total mess. Was this made in Inkscape??? I see clipping paths within clipping paths, clones, and groups - literally tons of crap in there.

Comment: Sorry what's the XML?

Comment: It's the structure of the code in the SVG file. You can open it inside Inkscape with the XML Editor (Shift+Ctrl+X) or just open the SVG in something like Notepad++. It's gonna take a lot of cleaning up.

Comment: Maybe try deleting the graphic that isn't working, and copy and paste a raster version of the graphic if you have access to it.

Comment: Ok i took a snapshot of the bottom left image and pasted into the svg file. Now it appears in the pdf file... so what exactly is the reason why it works now and didn’t before?

Comment: I think it was because the file had all those unnecessary clones and clipping paths, which just prevented it from working properly. As to how it happened, ultimately it depends on how the SVG was made.

Comment: Interesting. The "missing" part is actually inside the pdf. It shows up when extracting all raster images from the pdf using `pdfimages -all IPRk.pdf img`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complextity of the elements somehow seems to exceed limits of PostScript or PDF. If you save your SVG as Optimized SVG, you can reduce that complexity quite a bit.

While Inkscape still has the same problems with the optimized version, I used another app, [Sketch](https://www.sketch.com/) to open it and export the PDF, and it seems to work fine.

→ [PDF](https://aagd.de/downloads/IPRk.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I must admit analyzing SVGs properly, especially this one, is a little too complex for non-programmers. But do a workaround:

Make a bitmap copy of the problematic shape. It's in the Edit menu. Remove or close the original in the Objects panel.

You do not lose anything because it already seems to be rasterized, only wrapped in a complex way in the file structure and you said it's a PNG.

Be sure you have high enough resolution for bitmap creation, at least the same as your PNG would have in the final size or more. It's in the preferences.